# @OneToOne Spring Boot Jpa

Tags: java-ee, jpa, spring-boot

Tengo la siguiente clase :

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserBean extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "Username  cannot be null")
@Column
@Size(min = 4, max = 25, message = "Username can not be empty")
private String username;

@NotNull(message = "First Name cannot be empty")
@Column
@Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "First Name cannot be less than 3 characters")
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message = "Last Name cannot be empty")
@Column
private String lastName;

@Column
private String provider;

//Getter Setter
```

Y este es el objeto hijo que representa que esta asociado por el identificador del userbean:

```
@Table(name = "user_icons")
@Entity
public class UserBeanIcon implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
@Lob
private byte[] byteContents;


@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private UserBean userBean;
```

Recompilo Maven y recargo el proyecto y me genera las tablas y las relaciones en la base de datos. El problema es que la relacion que me genera es una OneToMany y no la OneToOne que esperaba...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué esperabas encontrar? Quiero decir... a fin de cuentas, una OneToOne no deja de ser más que una especialización de una ManyToOne (o OneToMany según el lado desde el que la mires) y, salvo que empieces a hacer cosas complejas con constraints, la forma de materializarlas en tu modelo físico es la misma. La única diferencia estará en las clases de tu modelo lógico (y, supongo, en las consultas que generará la implementación JPA que uses cuando tenga que instanciar esa relación)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el problema de base es que parte de la información sobre la estructura la controla JPA y que la BD solo ve la parte que JPA decide que vea, con lo cual la estructura de tablas puede ofrecer más funcionalidad de la estrictamente necesaria.

Además, no vemos directamente la estructura de tablas sino la representación gráfica de la herramienta de diseño<sup>1</sup>.

En la tabla `user_icons` acabas teniendo un campo de id y un campo de FK, y en ese campo FK puedes poner valores repetidos<sup>1</sup>

La mejor solución es, para `@OneToOne`, usar la misma clave en ambas tablas<sup>2</sup>. O, en otras palabras, que el FK de `user_icons` sea también el *primary key*, en lugar de un campo separado.

Puedes hacer eso usando [`@MapsId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html); en este ejemplo [explican como usarlo para `@OneToOne`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Básicamente, indicas que la relación ya está mapeada por el campo de Id (con lo cual tendrás el atributo en el *entity* pero en la base de datos usará el campo Id):

```
@Table(name = "user_icons")
@Entity
public class UserBeanIcon implements Serializable {

@Id // No "@GeneratedValue"
private Long id;
...
@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
private UserBean userBean;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Igual si le pones `unique = true` a la columna de FK, la restricción hace que la herramienta de BD identifique la relación como 1-a-1. O no.

<sup>2</sup> Que también es lo más razonable si diseñas las tablas desde el DER.